# What is the most stl-ish way to replace character in a std::string that are determined by predicate?

Tags: c++, string, stl

If I have a string `abc12df34`, I would like to replace say the digits with # and receive `abc##df##`.

What is the most stl-ish way to do this?

Comment: Have you seen [`std::replace_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/replace)?

Comment: Yeah, this will do it. Maybe it is so obvious, this is why nobody asked it before - but nowadays I am using stack overflow as documentation - which in this case failed me.

Comment: `QString & QString::replace(const QRegExp & rx, const QString & after)`  http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qstring.html

Comment: @user3528438 How does Qt apply to this question (i.e., what does it have to do with the STL)?

Comment: @JamesAdkison To show that the most stl-ish answer to this question is to imporve `std::string` to be at least as full-featured as `QString`.

Comment: @user3528438 Fair enough. To play devil's advocate, some may be inclined to think separation of data and algorithms is a strength.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to me, this would be:

http://ideone.com/bcd20z

```
int main()
{
    std::string s = "abc12df34";
    std::replace_if(s.begin(), s.end(), [](char c) { return isdigit(c); }, '#');
    std::cout << s << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming C++11 at least, I'd say for_each with a lambda function with iterators to individual char sending a reference to char.
Not sure about how fast it is, but STL-ish, I guess it's quite much :)

```
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string text("abc12df34";
    for_each(text.begin(), text.end(), [](char &current) {if (current >= '0' && current <= '9') current = '#';});
.....
}
```

EDIT : I've just read previous answer. I didn't know about is_digit and didn't think about std::replace_if. I guess it's a better way than mine. But both work :)

Answer (score 1):

Use [`std::transform`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) to transform the string and a lambda as a unary predicate.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string s("abc12df34");
    using std::begin;
    using std::end;
    std::transform(begin(s), end(s), begin(s), [&](char c)
    {
        return (c >= '0' && c <= '9') ? '#' : c;
    });

    std::cout << s << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not keep it simple and readable instead of trying to be "stl-ish":

```
for (char& ch : str) {
  if (isdigit(ch)) ch = '#';
}
```